# PHP mail may be filtered out by spam?

Tags: php

I am creating a small company, and would like to send out emails to my clients once they have signed up for my service to activate their accounts. I am currently using PHP's mail() function, however I am worried that my emails are being filtered out by spam filters. Is there a better way to go about this?

```
$email = 'XZY Client Email address @ somedomain.com';

$emailSubject = "Welcome to XYZ Service!";

$to = $email;
$subject .= "".$emailSubject."";
$headers .= "From: no-reply@XYZService.com\r\n" .
 "X-Mailer: php";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "Welcome to XYZ Service! \n Activate your account by clicking the following link: link...";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Is there a way to authenticate these emails so that my clients know that they are from my actual service? Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are lots of reasons messages get caught as spam.  HTML-only instead of multipart/mime including both plain & html is one of them. A `no-reply` from header is another. Some filters are aggressive, others are liberal.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski well I'm wondering if I use a service like http://www.campaignmonitor.com/ and send emails from xzy@xzyService.com, how will they be able to send my emails without getting swatted better than I can? What magic are they using...

Comment: They use carefully crafted and complete headers, and their outbound smtp servers are less likely to get blacklisted. If you are on a shared host, you can count on your host getting blacklisted from time to time when some other tenant gets his website compromised.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I see. And is there any way I can use a service like to this to send automated activation emails for me? Also, I am sending these emails fron a stand-alone Amazon EC2 instance, so I will not run into that problem..

Comment: I don't know how the 3rd party services work. Regarding EC2 however - and my experience may be a couple years out of date - EC2 IP ranges are highly likely to be blacklisted, owing to the fact that they are so easy to setup and tear down. They're very prone to being used as spam origins.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get your mail server white listed by some of the major postmasters (AOL, Gmail, Hotmail, etc.).

Comment: I failed to mention in my question that I am sending primarily to institutional email address, such as Bob@harvard.edu, or Bill@mit.edu etc...

Comment: Ah, that complicates the matter somewhat. I am not familiar with the postmasters for educational institutions, but I would be surprised if they had no whitelisting method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you can setup a mail server to handle all your emails.

Try using that mail server for sending emails and see if they are still filtered or not.

BTW, setting up a mail server on *nix systems is free and worth giving a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple arcade site that people from my highschool use and for quite a while I've been using the method that you showed. I didn't look at my code to verify that they're identical, but they look fairly close and mine works with gmail and all other big name services I've ran into!

Just remember that some hosting companies limit the amount of PHP mail that can be sent per minute. Mine only allows 9 per minute, I know I've gotten suspended a few times on accident while running test mail sends, haha.